# Conditioning Yes or No in C MessageBox()

Tags: c, winapi, conditional-statements, messagebox

I had a problem of conditioning what I want this MessageBox() to do when a user clicks "Yes" or "No".

Here is my pseudo code show what I mean:

```
MessageBox(0,"Click \"Yes\" or \"No\".","A MessageBox() Example",4);
    if(TheUserClickedYes){
        //Do something
    }else if(TheUserClickedNo){
       // Do Something else
    }
```

The 4 in the last parameter displays "Yes" or "No" buttons. I can get the box to display, but when I try to condition the buttons, I don't know how to do it. I tried to Google it and all that displayed in the results was C++ or C#. I am trying to do it in C. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will return an integer indicating which button was clicked, in case of success.

Rewrite your code to use the appropriate constants instead of hardcoding numbers:

```
switch (MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Click \"Yes\" or \"No\".", TEXT("A MessageBox() Example"), MB_YESNO)) {
case IDYES:
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Yes!"), TEXT("Yes"), MB_OK);
    break;
case IDNO:
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("No!"), TEXT("No"), MB_OK);
    break;
default:
    /* An error occurred. */
}
```

Always read carefully the documentation of the API you're using **before** using it.

Answer (score 0):

`MessageBox` has an integer result which tells about what user clicked.

See documentation for possible return values: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx

Also, using `4` instead of `MB_YESNO` is not a very good style.